# Add custom right-click Desktop context action on Mac

Tags: terminal, automator, shortcut-menu

I have seen variations of this question asked about 50 times, but never from the "Desktop". All are asking how to add right-click contextual actions from "Finder" or something else.

I'm a heavy Linux user. As such I tend to spend the bulk of my time in a terminal. While I've added a shortcut to my Launchpad, added a <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> hotkey, et cetera; nothing is exactly like being able to just right-click on my background and launch a terminal.

[image: Screenshot of the Finder contextual menu].

I'd really like to be able to add some sort of custom actions anywhere on this menu to directly open a terminal.

Comment: "The Desktop" ***is*** Finder. It's just a folder with a different graphical representation. The trouble with clicking on 'nothing' inside a folder is you don't get the same array of options you get if you right click a file.

Comment: I keep the Terminal launched at startup, so I can always switch to it, and open a new window/tab if necessary.

Comment: @Tetsujin, while that is interesting information to know, that doesn't actually answer my question does it? You've pointed out some interesting bits of info, but the question remains unsolved.

Comment: jkelley - It wasn't an answer, it was a comment. Answers go in the answer space below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Service Station](https://servicestation.menu) or perhaps [Context Menu](https://langui.net/context-menu/). Both allow you add items to Finder's context (right click) menu. They are both available in the Mac App Store.

The Context menu for my desktop is like this:

[image]

Note that you can't add items anywhere in the context menu.  The additions will always be at the bottom.

Comment: Good call, I ended up coming to this answer as well. I just wish there was a native way to do this without third party software.

Answer (score 0):

FinderMenu has worked perfectly for me to open a new terminal or text file.

Simple to install as well, working on MacOS Ventura 13.

You can get it here: https://github.com/samiyuru/custom-finder-right-click-menu

Comment: This is an identical answer to this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458766/119271